Burninate [gender] tag?
Currently there are 6 questions tagged gender.
I feel the tag is very narrow and used in a somewhat inconsistent way (see below). It can be better represented by other tags. In particular:

Does Chinese have a gender-neutral term for "homemaker"? [word-requests] is enough. It's not [terminology] because
What are Chinese terms for 'androgynous', 'gender neutral', 'non binary' etc. to imply gender neutrality? Better with [word-requests]. [colloquialisms] also fine as it asks specifically for that.
What kinship terms to use for spouses of aunts and uncles in same-sex relationships? [kinship] tag seems just fine
Men's and women's Chinese names [gender] tag is kinda
Should one write “妳好" when addressing a female? should have the [writing] tag
What is the ancient Chinese one-character name for woman like '子’ means man? should clean up the [classical-chinese] and [old-chinese] tags. [gender] is vaguely related

Given the small number of questions, and how vaguely the tag is used, I propose to retag and burninate.

Could the problem with the [gender] tag be that it's not used often enough?  There are questions that relate to gender that are not tagged gender, e.g., male or female.
